# Trigger Question

Tags: webservices, trigger

I am trying to write a trigger the executes when an opportunity is closed won & a value on a field within the related account is < 1. I am also looking to pass a few fields from the account back to the class.

Does anyone have any examples of anything similar I might be able to parse and learn from?

Also would I perhaps create this trigger from the account level rather than the opportunity.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Just use Process Builder.

Comment: I am an @future method and cant seem to make the in vocable method work.

Comment: Why are you in a @future context?

Comment: I am trying to execute a web service callout similar to this http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/03/16/restful-web-service-callout-using-post/

Answer (score 1):

Plently on TrailHead and others
https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm

Comment: Hey Eric, it'd be good to expand on this and actually include some content here. Links often break over time.